# App\Repositories\AdminRepository::getAllAdmins(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator, LengthAwarePaginator returned

Tags: laravel, pagination

I used `paginate` to display the database data but got the following error
`App\Repositories\AdminRepository::getAllAdmins(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator, Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator returned`

What namespace should I use to fix it?

This is my `AdminRepository.php`

```
<?php


namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\AdminRepositoryInterface as AdminRepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Requests\EditPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateAdmin;
use App\Http\Requests\DeleteAdmin;
use App\Http\Requests\EditAdmin;
use App\Services\AdminService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AdminRepository implements AdminRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getAllAdmins(int $count):Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator
    {
        return Admin::paginate($count);
    }
```

This is my `AdminRepositoryInterface.php`

```
namespace App\Repositories\Interfaces;

use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

interface AdminRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getAllAdmins(int $count):Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator;
```

Comment: This seems fairly obvious; if the error says you're returning the wrong type, you change the return type declaration on the method to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `getAllAdmins()` function is a type of `LengthAwarePaginator` because the [Laravel paginate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods) function return that type and your function return it. so, you should change the return type to `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` not `Paginator`.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

... 

public function getAllAdmins(int $count): LengthAwarePaginator
{
    return Admin::paginate($count);
}
```

Comment: At the company I work for, I said there is an abstract class called paginator that if I use it, the return type becomes a paginator.

Comment: If you want to use the abstracts as a return type you can use the `Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator` instead of `Paginator`

Comment: It&#39;s better to leave a comments in English to improve the community knowlage. btw, append your new edited code with editing this question or share it with me on social.

Comment: Use the `use` for using class and test it again

Comment: `Get all should not return Iterable ! return paginator instead of iterable‍`This is the message from the leader to me
Do you think he means AbstractPaginator?

Comment: **`AbstractPaginator`** work for me but i dont know Is there a goal for the company or not????

Comment: Ask your manager to exaclly what he want but both of abstract paginator and length aware paginator are correct for this case